# One-off Wordpress style changes: What method to use?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress but have an understanding of HTML/CSS. I recently fixed an issue on a site where a button wasn't being rendered properly.

I added the CSS changes to the custom CSS box for that particular page (the homepage). The changes worked on the editor preview but after saving and publishing the fix isn't live. I had thought that it might be a cache issue (WPEngine) but I did this two days ago. Shouldn't that be enough time for it to resolve?

I've cleared the cache on all my devices.

Is adding custom css in the WP Admin the way to fix this or does this need to be addressed in a different manor by uploading files or changes files via FTP?

Answer (score 0):

If you clear your cache and cookies in your browser you should be able to see your changes almost immediately if you add your CSS through the wp-admin custom css area.

A good way to check if that code is there is by viewing the source of your page and searching for the CSS in your dom.  If it is not there, but added into your custom css in the theme it might be a problem with your chosen theme.

If you change the theme's css directly through FTP you will want to keep in mind that if you ever update your particular theme, all your custom css will be overwritten and you will lose it.  You can see more on how to add custom css here:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/